# Dijkstra's algorithm for directed graphs with negative-weight edges

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

The following is an example of a directd graph with negative-weight edges for which Dijkstra's algorithm produces incorrect answers:

[image]

Applying the Dijkstra's algorihm, we get the following:

[image]

The path that we get from s to w is not the shortest. Therefore, we don't get right results.

How could we justify for the general case why we cannot apply the Dijkstra's algorithm on directed graphs with negative-weight edges?

Comment: move to math.stackexchange.com : not a programming question

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm works only on graphs with non-negative edge weights. Use bellman ford for graphs that have negative edge weights.

Comment: To justify, why an algorithm is not applicable, one example instance, that makes the algorithm fail, is enough.

Comment: There are about 5 questions in the "related questions" that ask this exact question.  But you seem to have already justified it by finding a counter-example, so what is your question?

Comment: @MarkPeters I wanted to know how it could be justified, without the use of a counter-example.